# Session scoped hashmap in Spring

Tags: java, spring, session

I'm trying to learn pure Spring and to do that i'm converting my Spring-boot application to spring with pure xml configuration.

My question is how can I obtain session scoped property through xml configuration?

Right now i've got this:

```
@Autowired
private
ConcurrentHashMap<String,Subscription> subscriptionConcurrentHashMap;
(...)
@Bean
@SessionScope
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Subscription> getConcurrentHashMap(){
    return new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
}
```

And it works, but i'm not sure how to define generic java class as session scoped bean in xml.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to this like that:

```
<bean name="subscriptionConcurrentHashMapBean" class="java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

and then just reference in controller bean:

```
<property name="subscriptionConcurrentHashMap" ref="subscriptionConcurrentHashMapBean"/>
```

Generic type of this hashMap apparently doesn't matter